# Strapi Upload file during entry creation

Tags: postman, strapi

I tried to upload an image to Strapi using postman, but I got with the following message:

```
When using multipart/form-data you need to provide your data in a JSON 'data' field.
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found the solution by filling the postman form like this
[postman screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myh5q.png)

Comment: For those who struggle uploading files through the standard endpoint: the key in the post data is 'files' .